# Why has Excel stopped offering to sort adjacent Columns?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

Xp3.
Excel 2003 (11.8346.8341) Sp3

In the past, whenever I selected a columns that was next to another column and selected "sort", Excel would offer to sort the adjacent columns well. This was very helpful as I have a numbered song list, not in alphabetical order.

Suddenly it has stopped, even in the same sheets it used to do this.

How can I get Excel to return to this previous behaviour?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Sorry: 2003 (11.8346.8341) Sp3 - Will edit everything

Comment: Everywhere I've looked said that you couldn't turn it off even if you wanted to (and many do).  If you figure out why yours isn't working, there will be many many people interested.

Comment: Is this in existing workbooks, or is it in new ones as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just highlight / select multiple columns... always worked for me.

EDIT:

click-drag to highlight columns/rows of data, or ctrl-click (or shift-click) on the column headers (A,B,C etc)  to highlight whatever data you want.

Click on 'tools -> sort data' (or whatever it's called now on the "ribbon"), if you've selected column headers, they should show up in three sub-sort categories, if now, then you'll only have the column letters shown.  from there, select ascending/descending as desired.

I've always done it this way.  If you don't select additional columns, then of course it won't sort adjacent columns of data.

I don't have any windows machines with any form of ms office, so can't provide a useful image from ms office.  Libreoffice?  Pretty much the same.

Comment: Could you maybe expand your answer a little? It's currently marked as "low quality". You could add a screenshot or explain in more detail. That'd be great!